# Hexadecimal To Decimal

Tags: code-golf, number

Read input of up to 8 characters presented as hexadecimal number and print this number as decimal number. In case that input can not be presented as hexadecimal input it has to print 0

**Rules:**
It is not allowed to use any function that takes or returns strings/characters, beside function that reads string/char from input and return strings/char as-is, function that takes integer and prints that integer to output as decimal number and function (if needed) that takes character and return its ASCII/UNICODE represented integer.

Shortest code wins

Example input
`C0cAc01a`

output
`3234512922`

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood the rules right; is it: (No fun a except (b, c, d)) or is it (No fun (a, except b), c, d)?

Comment: You are not allowed any functions that returns or accepts chars/strings except mentioned one. Is that clear?

Comment: @ralu you should narrow that down. Operators are functions. Methods are functions. If only in/out is accepted, how are we supposed to compute anything?

Comment: So im not quite sure here.. The function tonumber in lua is not allowed or is it?
I can do it in 38 characters if thats allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Ruby, 74 characters

```
n=0;p gets.gsub(/./).all?{|x|n=n*16+(x>?9?9:0)+x.ord%16;/[\da-f]/i=~x}?n:0
```

Input must be given on STDIN. With command line option `-ln` (counted as 4) it can be shortened to 69 characters.

```
n=0;p chars.all?{|x|n=n*16+(x>?9?9:0)+x.ord%16;/[\da-f]/i=~x}?n:0
```

Comment: With options `-ln` you mean `$_.chars` instead of `chars` probably?

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <del>114</del> 106

```
x#y=16*x+mod y 16
main=getLine>>=print.maybe 0(foldl(#)0).mapM(`lookup`zip"ABCDEF0123456789abcdef"[-6..])
```

Handles input of arbitrary size.

Answer (score 3):

### c -- 181

Input passed on the commandline (one argument only). Relies on K&R function typing defaults. ASCII specific, but has ***no*** reliance on the language or library to know how to parse numbers. Lots of characters given up to specifying a large integer type for this purpose.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(int c,char**v){unsigned long b=0;char*d=v[1]-1,e;while(e=*++d){
e-=(e>96)?87:(e>64)?55:(e>57)?33:(e>47)?48:0;if(e>15){b=0;break;}
b=b*16+e;}printf("%lu\n",b);}
```

### Ungolfed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(int c,char**v){
  unsigned long b=0;
  char*d=v[1]-1,e;
  while(e=*++d){
    if(e>'`')e-=87; // reduce lowercase letters to 10--
    if(e>'@')e-=55; // reduce uppercase letters to 10--
    if(e>'9')e-=33; // reduce punctioation immediately above the
                      // digits so it does not iterfere
    if(e>'/')e-='0';// reduce digits to 0-9
    if(e>15){b=0;break;} // terminate immediately on bad input
    b=b*16+e;
  }
printf("%lu\n",b);}
```

### Validation:

```
$ gcc -o dehex dehex_golfed.c 
$ ./dehex C0cAc01a
3234512922
$ ./dehex 1       
1
$ ./dehex 1f
31
$ ./dehex g 
0
$ ./dehex 1g
1
$ ./dehex 1:2
0
```

Comment: input 1:2 should return 0

Comment: Spoil sport. Pfffsssssththththth...and fixed.

Comment: Since you use `*d` quite often I think you can assign it to a new variable (`while(z=*++d)...`) and save some chars.

Comment: Yes. I'd meant to get around to that.

Comment: Just saw another one you may use for each `if`: `if(e>96)e-=87;` => `e-=e>96?87:0;` or if you like `e-=(e>96)*87;`. With latter you can also combine all those `if`s into one expression.

Comment: Oh. That's cute. But you can't combine the `()*` form the logic depend on sequence points between each operation (e must get updated). Another "ah!"...you can chain the trinary conditionals.

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion. That's what I meant.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that depends on the difference between signed and unsigned arithmetic (at least assuming two's complement representation, which seems reasonable enough), so you could just lose the `unsigned ` to save 9 chars.  Also, you could use `while(e=e>15?b=0:*++d)` to get rid of the `break`.

Comment: The `unsigned` was to get the largest available integer space supported by the '89 standard. because 16^8 = 2^32 means that a 32 bit signed integer wouldn't have the range to support the specified input. True, `long` is a 64 bit value on most modern machines but that isn't guaranteed so I wrote the code to get as close as possible to guaranteeing it consistent with the standard. The `while` improvement is nice.

Comment: Well, it was introduced in the c99 spec, but you could use long long to guarantee at least 64 bits without library dependence. You could also move the variable declaration to the global scope in order to take advantage of the fact that global variables automatically attain the value of ``0`` on creation. You can also save 7 characters by putting the ``&&e>15`` condition in to the while loop, getting rid of ``if(e>15){b=0;break;}``, and use ``e>15?0:b`` as the number variable for the printf.

Comment: `main(c,v)char**v;` is 2 shorter than `main(int c,char**v)`

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, <strike>127</strike> 119 characters (thanks trinithis!)

[Code-Golfed](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/6vzs9/):

```
function f(n){for(o=i=0,c=1;l=n[i++];)o*=16,l=l.charCodeAt(0),o+=l-(l>96?87:l>64?55:48);return /[\W_g-z]/i.test(n)?0:o}
```

[Formatted](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/vuzpV/):

```
function hexToDec(hexChars) {
    //Iterate through hex chars
    for (dec=i=0,count = 1; hexChar = hexChars[i++];) {
        dec *= 16;
        hexCharCode = hexChar.charCodeAt(0);

        //Get the hex number and add it
        hex = hexCharCode;
        if(hexCharCode > 96){
            hex -= 87;//For lower case letters
        } else if (hexCharCode > 64){
            hex -= 55;//For upper case letters
        } else {
            hex -= 48;//For numbers
        }
        dec += hex;
    }

    //Return 0 if invalid, decimal value otherwise
    if(/[\W_g-z]/i.test(hexChars)){
        return 0;
    }
    return dec;
}
```

Comment: `/[^(0-9|a-f|A-F)]/` -> `/[^0-9|a-f|A-F]/` -> `/[^0-9|a-f]/i` -> `/[\W_g-z]/i`

Comment: `return n.match(/regex/)?0:o` -> `return!/regex/.test(n)&&o`

Comment: @trinithis:  Thanks much, you are a regex-rockstar!  For the second one, I changed `match` to `test`, but decided to keep the original flow so it would return `0` instead of `false` for bad hex numbers (saved 1 char instead of 2).  Thanks again!

Comment: `o=i=0,c=1` -> `o=i=0`, `/[\W_g-z]/i.test(n)?0:o` -> `o*!/[\W_g-z]/i.test(n)`, `o*=16,l=l.charCodeAt(0),o+=l-(l>96?87:l>64?55:48)` -> `o=o*16+(l=l.charCodeAt(0))-(l>96?87:l>64?55:48)`

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby 1.9 (84)

```
gets.chomp!;n=0;p~/[^0-9A-Fa-f]/?0:($_.chars{|c|o=c.ord-48;n=16*n+(o>9?o%32-7:o)};n)
```

If we're allowed to use command line options, this is shortened to 72 characters + 4 for `-ln`:

```
n=0;p~/[^0-9A-Fa-f]/?0:($_.chars{|c|o=c.ord-48;n=16*n+(o>9?o%32-7:o)};n)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 106 characters

```
n=0
e=9e9
for c in raw_input():n=n*16+ord(c)-[e,48,e,55,e,87,e][sum(c>x for x in'/9@F`f')]
print[n,0][n<0]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Scheme, 24 chars

```
(string->number(read)16)
```

I hope this is not considered cheating. If it is:

```
(string->number(string-append "#x"(read)))
```

String to number conversion is mandatory.

In Scheme, if your program is not simple, something is wrong and you should start over until it is made simple. Scheme's power relies on removing restrictions instead of adding features so that the language can be easily extended. Scheme is, with Lisp-derived languages, a programmable programming language.

Comment: you are not following the rules

Answer (score 1):

### D 194 chars

```
void main(string[] a){ulong r;foreach(c;a[1]){switch(c){case '0'..'9':r+=c-'0';break;case 'a'..'f':r+=c-'a'+10;break;case 'A'..'F':r+=c-'A'+10;break;default: write(0); return;}r*=16;}write(r);}
```

I could get some profit by replacing the char literals with the numerals and get thus get rid of the +10 for the `a-f` but this doesn't depend on char encoding though D defines ascii support IIRC

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 64

By the rules:

```
FromDigits[#-If[#<58,48,If[#<97,55,87]]&/@ToCharacterCode@#,16]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 48 chars

```
function h(n){return 0/0==+("0x"+n)?0:+("0x"+n)}
```

### Formatted + Uncompressed

```
function h(n){
    if(+("0x"+n)==NaN) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return +("0x"+n);
    }
}
```

> The plus operator set before a string converts it into a **decimal** number. So I just had to prepend a "0x" and return 0 if it isn't a valid number to conform the rules.

Comment: Arguably, operators are just shorthand built-in functions, so in a way this is violating the rule "It is not allowed to use any function that takes or returns strings/characters". We also have two [standard](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1077/8478) [loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1658/8478) for these kinds of terminology quibbles.

Comment: @MartinBüttner JavaScript's plus operator is not intended to convert int to string. The language just automatically converts the string to an int because it saw the plus. Also there is no builtin function to add two numbers.

Comment: `function h(n){return+('0x'+n)||0}` does the same in 33 chars.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 74

```
i={it.inject(0){a,v->a*16L+('0123456789abcdef'.indexOf(v.toLowerCase()))}}
```

test case:

```
assert 3234512922 == i('C0cAc01a')
```

Not sure I understood the rules, though.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, 39 characters

```
print<>=~m/^[[:xdigit:]]{1,8}$/?hex$&:0
```

I kind of feel weird doing it this way in Perl but I believe it follows the rules, since the `hex()` function is a language construct and not a library function. If not...

### Perl, 64 characters

```
print<>!~m/^[[:xdigit:]]{1,8}$/?0:unpack 'L',reverse pack'H8',$&
```

I hope is fine.

Answer (score 0):

**C# - <strike>192</strike> 189**

oldschool, uses Console arguments for input, Console.WriteLine() for output. could possibly save a few chars, but can't get rid of most lengthy keywords. Makes evil use of foreach, ternary operator madness, bitwise complement ~ and signedness.
Reads any length input and aborts on bad characters ([^0-9a-fA-F]).

```
namespace _{class _{static void Main(string[]a){long b=0;foreach(int c in a.Length>0?a[0]:"")b=b<<4|(c-'0'<10?c-'0':c-'A'<6?c-'A'+10:c-'a'<6?c-'a'+10:~0L);System.Console.Write(b<0?0:b);}}}
```

A little deobfuscated (old ver):

```
using System;
namespace CodeGolf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            long ret = 0;
            int nextChar;

            while ((nextChar = Console.Read()) != '\r')
            {
                ret <<= 4;
                ret |= nextChar - '0' < 10 ? 
                        nextChar - '0' : 
                        nextChar - 'A' < 6 ? 
                            nextChar - 'A' + 10 : 
                            nextChar - 'a' < 6 ? 
                                nextChar - 'a' + 10 : 
                                ~0L;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(ret < 0 ? 0 : ret);
        }
    }
}
```

Would love to see a C# implementation in hardcore MSIL ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 98 chars

```
print sum(16**n*i for i,n in zip(((ord(c)|32)-[48,87][c>'9']for c in raw_input()[::-1]),range(9)))
```

A one-liner with the nifty bonus that you can use characters > 'f' for shorthand notation, e.g 'g' counts for 16, 'h' for 17 etc :D

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica <strike>93</strike> 92 chars

```
Fold[16 #1 + #2 &, 0,ToExpression[Characters@n /. Thread@Rule["a"~CharacterRange~"f", 10~Range~15]]]
```

Not as streamlined as Mr.Wizard's answer, but I'll include it for variety. It makes use of no native base conversion routines.  There is a shortcoming in my answer: I assumed that characters `a` to `f` would be given in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl - 77 chars

```
@h{0..9,'a'..'f'}=0..15;$n+=$h{lc$_}*16**($a++-1)for reverse split//,<>;say$n
```