# What are these letters?

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion

So what might be the shortest language for this simple task?

### Task:

You are given an input of type `String` - the string is a `valid` hexadecimal number (`[0-9A-F]`). 
Convert it to a decimal number and print it to the console.

### Tests:

```
HEX -> DEC
1 -> 1
98 -> 152
539 -> 1337
1337 -> 4919
A5F9 > 42489
F -> 15
```

### Win Condition:

This is code golf - shortest code wins.

### Rules:

- You **must** take the input(like function parameter) as String.
- You **must** return the result as String.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68247/8478)

Comment: Are quotes allowed in the input? e.g. "98"

Comment: @recursive *"The string is a valid hexadecimal number ([0-9A-F])"* The regex wouldnt match `"`, so no.

Comment: Why do we have to use the standard streams, instead of, e.g., function arguments?

Comment: @Dennis to make it more tricky - `stdin` is string for every language I know, so the crux is to convert it couple of times...

Comment: @0x45 But the input needs to be a string anyway (not a decimal number), so what's the added difficulty? Also, `⎕` is stdin **as number** in APL.

Comment: Updated the task @Adám

Comment: Printing a *number* to stdout/stderr constitutes returning a string, right?

Comment: What about languages which can only handle numbers (and therefore I/O strings as list of ASCII codes)?

Comment: Convert the ASCII to Char and then concatenate to a String  @Adám

Comment: @Adám printing to stdout is String, yes.

Comment: *Convert the ASCII to Char*? But the whole point is that such a language has no concept of character data.

Comment: Repost of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3741/hexadecimal-to-decimal ?

Comment: @l4m2 I thought of flagging this question for the same reason but the other question was closed. Would the best path to be to edit that 2015 question to be more clear and re-open it?

Comment: Why the requirement to output as a string? Trivial as this challenge may be, that requirement adds absolutely nothing to it.

Comment: Can the letters in the hex be lowercase?

Comment: @Engineer Toast I think you meant the 2011 one? The 2015 one that Martin Ender linked is the opposite conversion. With regards to the 2011 one, it does have two clear restrictions (NaN -> 0, length limit of 8) that this question doesn't have (and then everything else is a little murky), so would we be replacing it entirely or merging the restrictions of both questions?

Comment: Is it OK to add a leading `0` to the output?  I.e. `042489`
What about a trailing `.`?  I.e. `42489.`

Comment: @Wernisch leading 0 okay, `.` not.

Comment: @Pandacoder I *did* mean the 2011, thanks. I had gotten the two confused. That makes a difference, too. After 6.5 years, it's probably better to improve this question rather than re-open the old one.

Comment: @EngineerToast usually you don't come back from -12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f4/9/S1cA)

---

Am I missing something? I feel like... I feel like I am.

---

If "print as a string" implies "surround result with quotes":

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
H'".ø
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fQ11J7/CO//8tXQE)

---

05AB1E is based in Python, so it doesn't really matter if it's a string, integer or whatever; `H` will convert an integer, a string, a Ferrarri or 27 gnomes on patrol into hex. Given, the latter two aren't valid, it will error upon trying to execute or return the original string with no function applied.

Comment: [Aww man](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f4/9/I3OF9Lz83NRihfw8hYLEkqL8HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```hs
show.abs.read.("0x"++)
```

Thanks to @user9549915 for saving a byte

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzvzgjv1wvMalYryg1MUVPQ8mgQklbW/N/bmJmnoKtQm5igW@8gkZBaUlwSZFPnl6apkK0kqGSjpKlBZAwNbYEkobGxuZAyk0p9v@/5LScxPTi/7rJBQUA)

Comment: Question updated. You might save some bytes now

Comment: You can save a byte by using `abs` instead of `(+0)`

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>20</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

Thanks to l4m2 for catching my stupid mistake and saving me a byte. :)

```javascript
x=>'0x'+x-0+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvRCoIwFIDh@z2Fd2fDFEWiLCZ0I/QYY57FQnZsm2GIz76ym5/v5n@qtwra2ykWjgZMRqZFdlAtkC9FlQMkj6/ZeuTgUQ2jdQii1D9HvLuI3iiNfLVumuNl8qQxhDLEwbpNlOQ4/I/DXtmtJA3fKa6aXKARy5EePH4mJJNRDhnkJDaRatae2bFpWd00J3Y79i3rvw)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 15 bytes

```javascript
x=>'0x'+x-[]+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvRCoIwFIDh@z2Fd2djKYlIWSh0I/QM0cWYx1jIztpmGOKzW3bz8938T/VWQXvjYmqpw7Wv16luYD@BnNLbXQKsHl@j8cjBo@oGYxFEpn@OeLURfa808tlYN8aT86QxhCzEzthFZGQ5/I/d1rqZqe75RnHWZAMNmA304PHjkPqEJCQgSSxizVl1ZGVRsbwoDuxSthVrvw)

## Original 20 bytes

```javascript
l=>''+parseInt(l,16)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtRC8IgFEbf/SMqLWGMVRs46GXQzxC9C0OudnW9RL/dspePw@F8D/My2ZJP5YjRQd10DXrh/JAMZbhhEaHrT7ISPHdPIDiBccEjcKnsj0trgDZjQbw9pr3MiaKFnFUuzuNHqoiC/x9dW73YiDkGUCHexSaak1LWnk0XNg4T64fhzK7jOrH1Cw)

Comment: `-[]` => `-0` lol

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 18 bytes

My first JS golf!

```javascript
x=>''+eval('0x'+x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvRCsIgFEDf/ZGrrKQxRi3YoJdBnyF6DUOupm4Mom@31svhcOA81aqyTi6WIwWD1Y51GyeABlflOZw2aDZRE74Wl5BDQmW8IwQh9c8L3qlgskojfzuKS7nGFDTmLHMxjj5CBuLwPw47x0kHysGj9OHBLd@bEKK2bLiwvhtY23Vnduvngc1f)

Just prepends `0x` to the input and evaluates that, since it then represents a hexadecimal number in JS. Finally, we need to concatenate the empty string to convert to string.

Comment: no `eval` required

Comment: @l4m2 Yeah I realized that after seeing this improvement to mine, and thanks to op order I was able to drop () too

Comment: @l4m2 So now what? If I change this, then my solution will be identical to Pandacoder's, though we arrived to it independently.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 20 bytes

```python
lambda s:`int(s,16)`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKiEzr0SjWMfQTDPhf0ERkKOQpqFuaGxsrq75HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 6 bytes

```
":@dfh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDBToQwEIbvPMXIwS6Jkt3FjS5Gg5pwMh72atQUmLJVaLGUZPfiq@MUUPbQmX@mk@/PzGfvh8AE3MXA4AKWENO7DOFp95z2fpwUYt8H3stjCAZ5wbMKwR4b1AJEp3IrtfKmmggLlmldIVfslrXWSFWSkMpiiYaUqDS3lHNdNxUeSGX6gIXLslRdTcJwh@SVAzTctAgnxLFRSYvmdGI2mBp/PlM52/0jR9f2WGfagSbkepZXLIBG5l8/sIb3EKKzeOl5hXVLvsErYL7XyeK70xbpaAxkC3y433iLwPMstsP0MMmY/5EUNhEUxq/z8B7Yivy2NxQ20ZbiKoquKT1sUlelrP8F) (Contains a test suite, including type checking the parameters and the return value.)

This is pretty simple:

```
":@dfh
   dfh    obtain *d*ecimal *f*rom *h*ex
  @       then
":        format the result (cast to string)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
⁾0x;ŒVṾ
```

This is a monadic link that takes a string as argument and returns a string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R4z6DCuujk8Ie7tz3/1HDHEMgtrQAEqbGliCusbE5kHI0dQPx3B41zD3c/qhpTeR/LgA)

#### How it works

```
⁾0x;ŒVṾ  Monadic link. Argument: s (string)

⁾0x;     Prepend "0x" to s.
    ŒV   Eval as Python code.
         This returns the result as an integer.
      Ṿ  Uneval; turn the integer into its string representation.
```

Comment: It seems to work fine on TIO without `Ṿ`.

Comment: Works perfectly, yes. The challenge explicitly asks to return a string though. :/

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 23 bytes

```
0l1=?n88+*{'0'-:a)7*-+!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yDH0NY@z8JCW6ta3UBd1ypR01xLV1vx////usWJpmmWAA)

If the hex can be contain lowercase letters instead of uppercase, we can do it in 17 bytes:

```
0l1=?n88+*{e0p +!
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 24 bytes

```java
s->Long.valueOf(s,16)+""
```

Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##lY5NC4JAEIbP669YPLlUgkkfIgURRIeiQ8fosOmoW7Yr7ipF@NtN@yA77ml4Z@Z5Zs60pAORAT@HlzorTikLcJBSKfGWMo4fBmJcQR7RAPAabkvBS8ibRjtBe5UzHuMEbsMQAusXiW@gykAfn1RUNaUULMTXxvpZPBwxzWNJXqo/d9INM1zLwXwjeGyXNC1gF1my74xJzzT9GiG//eMuFVxtUSg7a8wq5VZXYX8fNB2TEC3Am@oSI9fTRRzXnegyi9FK@87qDVRGVT8B).

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
Ｉ⍘↧Ｓ¹⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwymxODW4BMhP1/DJL08tSgbyNTzzCkpLoKKamjoKhmaamprW//87mrpZ/tctywEA) Link is to verbose version of code. Save 1 byte if the input can be in lower case. Charcoal doesn't automatically convert numbers to decimal on output, so the cast operator is necessary anyway. Explanation:

```
   Ｓ    Input string
  ↧     Lower case
    ¹⁶  Literal 16
 ⍘      Base conversion
Ｉ       Cast to string
        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 14 bytes

```
=0&HEX2DEC(A1)
```

Concatenates a leading `0` to convert to String.  I.e. `042489`

---

## Excel, 20 bytes

```
=TEXT(HEX2DEC(A1),0)
```

Naive solution.

---

Format both outputs verified as String (`=T(B2)`)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <strike>5</strike> 4 bytes

`iz16`

Parses input as a hex number and returns the base 10 equivalent.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 3 bytes

```
i|H
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=i%7CH&i=1%0A98%0A539%0A1337&m=2)

`i` ensures that the input doesn't get automatically evaluated as an integer, and `|H` converts from/to hexadecimal.  The link above is for the online interpreter, but the language really does use `stdin` and `stdout`.  The C# implementation of the language does this, which is available from the repository above.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 27 bytes

```r
paste(strtoi(scan(,""),16))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyCxuCRVo7ikqCQ/U6M4OTFPQ0dJSVPH0ExT878hl6UFl6mxJZehsbE5l9t/AA)

`strtoi` will always return a number of type `integer` which is a signed 32-bit integer type, and `paste` implicitly converts to `character`, as required.

Comment: I don't know the details about this language, but you aren't taking from `stdin` are you?

Comment: @0x45 well...sorta. `scan()` takes input from `stdin` except that `stdin` will in certain circumstances (like on TIO) redirect to the file so while _technically_ on TIO it's not `stdin`, it's equivalent.

Comment: Question updated. You might save some bytes now

Comment: @0x45 nah it's the same either way. Thank you, though.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with R, but it seems you are returning an integer instead of a string (as per the challenge rules).

Comment: @O.O.Balance ah, I see. Must have missed that a while back. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ØHiÐ€ɠ’ḅ⁴Ṿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9qZWxsef//w5hIacOQ4oKsyaDigJnhuIXigbThub7/wqLhuYQkNsKhyKfigbj/MQo5OAo1MzkKMTMzNwpGCkE1Rjk)

### How it works

```
ØHiÐ€ɠ’ḅ⁴Ṿ - Main link, no arguments

ØH         - Yield the string “0123456789ABCDEF”. Call that H
     ɠ     - Read a line from STDIN, e.g. “A5F9”. Call that A
   Ð€      - For each character in A
  i   ’    - Get the 0-based index of that character in H
        ⁴  - Yield 16
       ḅ   - Convert from base
         Ṿ - Convert to string
```

Comment: Question updated. You might save some bytes now

Comment: @0x45 Oddly enough, I doubt it. Reading from STDIN takes one byte here `ɠ`, but if the input cannot be surrounded by `"`, then it would automatically be evaluated, which `ɠ` doesn't do, and unevaluating could take more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 5 bytes

```
16i?p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/QLNO@4P9/N1NXAA)

Rather trivial. If input really needs to be a *string* vs. the language's natural hex input, then `16i?xp` [takes care of that in 6 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/QLNO@ouD//2g3U9dYAA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 23 bytes

```julia
!s=dec(parse(Int,s,16))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/9fsdg2JTVZoyCxqDhVwzOvRKdYx9BMU/N/QVFmXklOnoaikrGppZImF4LvaOqGKuCmpPkfAA)

`dec` appears to be shorter than `repr` or `string`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 14 bytes

```ruby
p gets.to_i 16
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhPbWkWK8kPz5TwdDs/383AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes

```apl
⍕16⊥(⎕D,⎕A)⍳⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OA5KPeqYZmj7qWagCFXXSAhKPmo97Nj7oW/f@fpqBubGKqzgWkHU3dLMEMN3UA)

Comment: `16⊥⍞⍳⍨⎕D,⎕A` as a full program prints to stdout and so doesn't require `⍕`.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 4 bytes

Outputting as a string doubles the byte count!

```
nG s
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=bkcgcw==&input=Ijg4ODg4ODg4IgotUQ==)

Comment: I had `nG` before the [OP said we couldn't have quotes in the input](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161935/what-are-these-letters#comment392200_161935). And the output has to be a string? -__-

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 15 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a0x%1
```

If input via command-line argument is unacceptable, then for 26 bytes:

```
@set/ph=
@cmd/cset/a0x%h%
```

Answer (score 1):

## WinDbg, 15 bytes

```
.printf"%d",$u0
```

Input is done by first setting the pseudo-alias `$u0` with the input string and then running the code (eg- to set pseudo-alias: `r$.u0=a5f9`).

Prints the input, conversion from hex to decimal is implicit.

How it works:

```
.printf"%d",        $$ Prints a decimal
            $u0     $$ The decimal to print
```

If the extra sugar that WinDbg prints when evaluating an expression is allowed:

### WinDbg, 4 bytes

```
?$u0
```

How this one works:

```
?                  $$ Evaluates an expression
 $u0               $$ The expression to evaluate
```

This one would have output like this (for input= A5F9):

```
Evaluate expression: 42489 = 0000a5f9
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# .NET, 34 bytes

```csharp
s=>System.Convert.ToInt32(s,16)+""
```

I have the feeling this is overly long, but the alternative `s=>int.Parse(s,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)+""` is even worse..

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jcxBC4IwGMbxu5/iZaeNTLBhJaUQgRDkqaCzrBkD22DvEiL87CvJQ7d2euDhx1/gXBgrvegaRKhfEQC6xikBvVFXqBulKRtfgNMTnbwn1UOLLTqr9C2G75bQQgEei3Iye6N7aV1yNgft@IJinC7ZjBA/dja/tY9E08nkYpWTR6UlbSlJCWP/Vb4OYhnPg1zK@SoI7rIqrFhNaogG/wY)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-lp`, 6 bytes

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -lp
$_=hex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYjteL/fze3f/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 24 bytes

```
method(x,x fromBase(16))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/n6ZgZasQ8z83tSQjP0WjQqdCIa0oP9cpsThVw9BMU/N/moaSoZKmQkFRZl5JTh4XkGtpgco3NbZEFTA0NjZHFXE0dUNT44bg/gcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 20 bytes

```
proc D n {expr 0x$n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFFIU@hOrWioEjBoEIlr/Z/Tm5igUKqQjWXIZelBZepsSWXobGxOZejqZsll1utQnVBaUmxgkqqVYxCtAuQjq39DwA)

Comment: Alternative approach: **21 bytes** https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFFIU@hujg5MU9BJU9BtaL2f05uYoFCqkI1lyGXpQWXqbEll6GxsTmXo6mbJZdbrUJ1QWlJsYJKqlWMQrQLkI6t/Q8A

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 19 bytes

```
puts [expr 0x$argv]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCE6taKgSMGgQiWxKL0s9v///46mbpYA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 15 bytes

```
str..int$(?,16)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfmfZhvzv7ikSE8vM69ERcNex9BM83@0uqG6jrqlBZAwNbYEkobGxuZAytHUDcRzU49VqLFTyE0sUNFI0wQxC4qAuvX0cjKLS/4DAA)